# Rescaling and linear interpolation

Tags: interpolation

Is **rescaling** as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value) and [**linear interpolation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) two names for the same thing or are there any differences between them?

Comment: In short: yes. If you want to change scales you can use interpolation.

Comment: No they are not, rescaling is exact whereas interpolation ain't. Rescalling is a linear map between sample spaces, whereas linear interpolation is a map from a sample space to a function space.